# how to displaying microsoft word content in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using third party application PHPWord_0.6.2_Beta to displaying microsoft word content in to web page with codeigniter, but I don't find tutorial do that, just find this tutorial who used to create ms word file and writing inside that.

```
$this->load->library('word');
 //our docx will have 'lanscape' paper orientation
$section = $this->word->createSection(array('orientation'=>'landscape'));
$section->addText('Hello I am tester');
$section->addTextBreak(1);
$section->addText('I am inline styled.', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
$section->addTextBreak(1);
$this->word->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, 'size'=>16));
$this->word->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText('I am styled by two style definitions.', 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
$section->addText('I have only a paragraph style definition.', null, 'pStyle');
$filename='test.docx'; //save our document as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($this->word, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

how to displaying microsoft word content into web page in codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/src/PhpWord)
2. Extract Zip.(You will get 3 files)
3. copy `phpword` folder and `phpword.php` file to `third_party` folder inside `application` Folder.
4. Create a new library inside your CodeIgniter’s `application/libraries`. Let’s call it `Word.php`
5. paste this code inside `word.php`

[Check this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104942/codeigniter-and-phpword/39105214#39105214)

---

`<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');`

```
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord.php"; 
 
class Word extends PHPWord { 
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 
}
```

and in controller use this

```
<?php

$this->load->library('word');//load librerry as usual


$section = $this->word->createSection(array('orientation'=>'portrait'));

$section->addText('Hello I am tester');
$section->addTextBreak(1);

$section->addText('I am inline styled.', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
$section->addTextBreak(1);

$this->word->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, 'size'=>16));
$this->word->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText('I am styled by two style definitions.', 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
$section->addText('I have only a paragraph style definition.', null, 'pStyle');

$filename='test.doc'; //save our document as this file name

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($this->word, 'Word2003');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

if this  not work add this lines too

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $last_update).' GMT');
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

[set_header Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7259975/4595675)

Comment: I  have tried your code and succesfull, but I just want to read file content from microsoft word not creating or writing inside it.

Comment: so that you can use `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()`, and `ob_end_clean()` as well.